# Why is my JSONModel Class being treated as a NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, api, model, jsonmodel

This is my JSON fetched from the API:

```
 {
categories =     (
            {
        icon =             {
            prefix =     "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/food/italian_";
            suffix = ".png";
        };
        id = 4bf58dd8d48988d110941735;
        name = "Italian Restaurant";
        pluralName = "Italian Restaurants";
        primary = 1;
        shortName = Italian;
    }
);
hasPerk = 0;
id = 4b5bed2ef964a520971d29e3;
location =     {
    address = "HS-5";
    cc = IN;
    city = "New Delhi";
    country = India;
    crossStreet = "Kailash Colony Market";
    distance = 4061;
    formattedAddress =         (
        "HS-5 (Kailash Colony Market)",
        "New Delhi 110024",
        Delhi,
        India
    );
    labeledLatLngs =         (
                    {
            label = display;
            lat = "28.55272788981442";
            lng = "77.24192322690806";
        }
    );
    lat = "28.55272788981442";
    lng = "77.24192322690806";
    postalCode = 110024;
    state = Delhi;
};
name = "The Big Chill Cafe";
referralId = "v-1546605733";
}
```

And here is my model class:

```
@interface LocationModel : JSONModel

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger distance;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger postalCode;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *address;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *cc;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *city;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *country;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *crossStreet;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *lat;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *lng;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *state;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *formattedAddress;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *labeledLatLngs;
@end


@protocol VenueModel;

@interface VenueModel : JSONModel

@property (nonatomic) NSArray *categories;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL hasPerk;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *id;
@property (nonatomic) LocationModel *location;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *referralId;
@end

@interface Restaurant : JSONModel
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger confident;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray <VenueModel*> *venues;
@end
```

Now, I am trying to get the values like this:

```
restaurant = [[Restaurant alloc] initWithDictionary

 [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSON            
options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil][@"response"] error:&error];

VenueModel *obj = [restaurant.venues firstObject];
LocationModel *locationObj = obj.location;
```

The values are coming fine till the VenueModel object, after that when I am trying to access the LocationModel object, i.e

```
LocationModel *locationObj = obj.location
```

, its throwing the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI location]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001b82880
```

Somebody please help me out, I need the location object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSJSONSerialization will produce NSDictionaries, NSArrays, NSStrings, NSNumbers and a few other basic types from a JSON string.

Your idea to initialize a custom object (`[[Restaurant alloc] initWithDictionary...`) is the right idea, but that idea must be applied to nested structures as well.  So, for example, the `Restaurant` initializer must apply that idea to its `venues` array.

Otherwise, you'll get the crash you're getting, treating one of the venue objects as if its a `VenueModel` instead of what it really is (an NSDictionary).

You didn't post `initWithDictionary`, but it needs to look something like this, especially the part where the objects *it contains* are initialized...

```
- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    self = [super init];
    // ...
    self.venues = [NSMutableArray array];
    if (self) {
        for (NSDictionary *venueDictionary in dictionary[@"venues"]) {
            VenueModel *venue = [[VenueModel alloc] initWithDictionary:venueDictionary];
            [self.venues addObject:venue];
        }
    }
    // and so on, for every other object type nested in dictionary
    return self;
}
```

Moreover, as you can see, `VenueModel` must also follow this practice, turning the location data into a `LocationModel`, and so on...